# Can't access docker container from host (osx)

Tags: node.js, express, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm using docker-compose, trying to run it on my development machine, I find that when I try to connect to my api using localhost it sends an empty response

```
MacBook-Air:api lucas$ curl localhost:3001
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

when I stop docker, I get this response:

```
MacBook-Air:api lucas$ curl localhost:3001
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 3001: Connection refused
```

That means that something happens on my localhost when I run Docker, but for some reason I can't access my api.

What I've tried:

-Running my express app @ 0.0.0.0 host instead of localhost

-Running:

```
docker inspect api
"Gateway": "172.18.0.1",
"IPAddress": "172.18.0.3",
```

and trying to curl those 2 ips (curl 172.18.0.1:3001)

This is the important part of my docker-compose file:

```
api:
  container_name: api
  networks:
    - app
  ports:
    - "0.0.0.0:3001:3001"
networks:
  app:
```

I had no clue what it could be, I'm also beginning with Docker so I'm not sure what other tests can I do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I just fixed it.

The problem was the following: when I run my server on production it uses HTTPS, and I was accessing my localhost via HTTP.